# Sound cannot be unmuted on windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows, audio

My laptop has some strange issues with the sound system.

The sound works normally usually, but if the sound is ever muted, it cannot be unmuted without restarting the computer. The computer shows the sound as muted and I can adjust it to any setting, but the computer will not play any sound unless it is restarted. Any clue to what the problem is?

Comment: Does the laptop have a *mute* key combo? Does that fail, as well as the Windows volume control?

Comment: Try to reinstalling the sound card driver————laptop manufacturer driver or Microsoft driver.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik sorry for the ultra late response but if the sound every reaches 0, even if i turn it back up no sound plays